# VB.net Parsing XML (attribute) youtube gdata

Tags: xml, vb.net, youtube

Greetings guys this is my first visit in here
I got a problem getting some data out of an xml file

The VB code is

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If (ComboBox1.Text = "") Then

        MessageBox.Show("No file name entered")

    Else


        Dim document As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/kavvsona")

        While (document.Read())

            Dim type = document.NodeType

            If (type = XmlNodeType.Element) Then

                If (document.Name = "yt:statistics/viewCount") Then

                    xmlMyName.Visible = True
                    xmlMyName.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()

                End If

                If (document.Name = "yt:statistics/viewCount/") Then

                    xmlMyEmail.Visible = True
                    xmlMyEmail.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()

                End If

                If (document.Name = "viewCount") Then

                    xmlMyTel.Visible = True
                    xmlMyTel.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()

                End If

                If (document.Name = "Notes") Then

                    xmlMyNotes.Visible = True
                    xmlMyNotes.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()

                End If

            End If

        End While


    End If

End Sub
```

And the xml file is available under this link http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/kavvsona

I want extract following information :

```
<yt:statistics lastWebAccess='1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' subscriberCount='9574' videoWatchCount='0' viewCount='120873' totalUploadViews='2374024'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i1.ytimg.com/i/T1ybzRP4iTT7NU6qbhV24g/1.jpg?v=51064230'/><yt:username>kavvsona</yt:username>
```

I have got no idea how to get it out of the yt: thing and the attribute. Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **[XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)** for this kind of XML parsing task:

```
Imports System.Xml.XPath
...
Dim nsManager As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(New NameTable())
nsManager.AddNamespace("yt", "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007")

Dim xml As XDocument = XDocument.Load("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/kavvsona")
Dim statsElement As XElement = DirectCast(xml.XPathEvaluate("//yt:statistics", nsManager), IEnumerable).Cast(Of XElement)().Single()
Dim usernameElement As XElement = DirectCast(xml.XPathEvaluate("//yt:username", nsManager), IEnumerable).Cast(Of XElement)().Single()

Dim viewCount As Int32 = Int32.Parse(statsElement.Attribute("viewCount").Value)
Dim username As String = usernameElement.Value

MessageBox.Show(username & ": " & viewCount)
```

Result:

```
kavvsona: 120873
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the XMLTextReader Class, check out the [GetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c932kx5.aspx) method.